# How to avoid html encoding of strings in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, partial-views

My goal is to separate js controls into partial views and parametrize them through ViewData. I want to pass a string in ViewData that is used as javascript string value.

Now the problem is that I don't know how to render a string that is not html encoded.

My current attempt is:

```
var domAsString = "<%: HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((string)ViewData["domLayout"]) %>"
```

Which renders it as a html-encoded string. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC? The "ViewData" part gave it away. And if yes, which version?

Comment: Yes, you're right: MVC 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
var domAsString = "<%= (string)ViewData["domLayout"] %>"
```

The `<%: %>` syntax is shorthand for `<%= Html.Encode( .... ) %>`

Comment: Thank you - Neil. Such a elementary mistake from me! This shows what happens when one starts to work with new framework :D

Comment: No problem. I do think the new syntax is nicer, once you're used to it. That was introduced in ASP.NET 4.0